# Navigate back to component, cannot refresh state

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying to load the relevant video `react-native-youtube` standaloneplayer,  depending what params are passed to the component.

It works fine on first load, but when I click the back button and navigate back to the page using `react-navigation` and with a different `id`, the video is the same - how can I change the player with new props:

```
   <Text
      onPress={() => {
        NavigationService.navigate("VideoPlayer", { id });
      }}
      style={styles.text}
    >
```

My videoplayer component:

```
 class VideoPlayer extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { id: propId } = NavigationService.getParams();
    const { videos } = this.props;

    // videos is array of objects
    let videoProps = videos.find(obj => obj.id == propId);

    let { id, icon, title, description, youtubeVideo, preview } = videoProps;
    const url = `https://img.youtube.com/vi/${youtubeVideo}/0.jpg`;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            YouTubeStandaloneAndroid.playVideo({
              apiKey: "AIzaSyBXX5qe0B2hb1HzvIvExJZbqspeG9dg0Dk",
              videoId: youtubeVideo,
              autoplay: true,
              lightboxMode: true,
              startTime: 124.5
            })
              .then(() => console.log("Android Standalone Player Finished"))
              .catch(errorMessage => console.log(errorMessage))
          }
        >
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: url }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{description}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    videos: state.videos
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try replacing `navigate` with the `push` action. The difference is that once a route from a stack is visited once, navigate will take you to it without mounting it again. With push you can mount the same route multiple times with different parameters. Here is more info from the official docs:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#push